Linear Diophantine-related Equations Question with 4 variables?
Let x, y, k, and w all be positive integers such that $43x+29y=kw$ and $4x+17y=k$. Find the least possible value of (k+w+x+y).
This problem was from a past contest I took, and I already know the answer is 55 from the answer sheet attached with the problem. I tried to use the Euclidean algorithm to get a relationship between x and y, and got (-2kw, 3kw) for the 1st equation and (-4k, k) for the 2nd. I'm stuck at how to progress.
One approach I tried was setting the 2 coordinates equal, which results in w=2, 1/3, where I took the first solution to w since the question asked for integers. Then I plugged w back in and combined the 2 equations, which eventually gets me 7x-y=0, in which the smallest solution pair for x and y while satisfying the condition is (1, 7). After that, I got k=123, so the solution I got was 123+2+1+7=133, but it's 55. Can someone explain why 55 is the correct solution?

It comes from $x=6$, $y=1$, $k=41$, $w=7$ but I don't see a nice way to get there.

Evidently at the minimum $(x, y)=1$, else we may divide $x, y, k$ by their gcd.
Eliminating $k$, we may write $y=\dfrac{43-4w}{17w-29}x$.   Now for $x, y>0$, we must have $2\leqslant w \leqslant 10$, which limits choices to $9$ cases.
As $(x,y)=1$, we can list the unique possibility for $x,y$ in each case and compute $5x+18y+w$ to find the minimum at $(w,x,y)=(7,6,1)$.
